# Strange behavior of #pragma pack

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, pragma, gcc4.4

I am facing a strange issue when using `#pragma pack`.

I have the following structs:

1. `st_a`: packed with `#pragma pack(1)`. Size = 1 byte. Contains bitfields.
2. `st_b`: packed with `#pragma pack(2)`. Size = 14 bytes.
3. `st_c`: packed with `#pragma pack(2)`. Size = 16 bytes. Contains `st_a` and `st_b`
4. `st_d`: packed with `#pragma pack(2)`. Size = 16 bytes. Contains `st_a` and contents of `st_b` (`st_b`'s members)

So, since `st_a` is of 1 byte packed under `#pragma pack(1)`, and since it's inside `st_c` which is packed under `#pragma pack(2)`, there should be one extra byte of padding in `st_c` immediately after `st_a` and that extra byte should be followed by contents of `st_b` which is a character buffer of even length (10).

But, this thing works strangely when I take the contents of `st_b` out and put them directly in `st_a`. The padding is seen after the character buffer, rather than before (See output below).

Can somebody explain, why this strange behavior occurs?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct A {
    int a : 1;
    int b : 1;
    int c : 1;
    int d : 1;
    int e : 1;
    int f : 1;
    int g : 1;
    int h : 1;
} st_a;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct B {
    unsigned char buf[10];
    int x;
} st_b;

typedef struct C {
    st_a temp1;
    st_b temp2;
} st_c;

typedef struct D {
    st_a temp3;
    unsigned char buf1[10];
    int x1;
} st_d;
#pragma pack(pop)

void print_hex(unsigned char* packet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%x ", packet[i]);
    } printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    st_c one;
    one.temp1.a = 0;
    one.temp1.b = 0;
    one.temp1.c = 1;
    one.temp1.d = 0;
    one.temp1.e = 0;
    one.temp1.f = 0;
    one.temp1.g = 0;
    one.temp1.h = 0;
    memcpy(&one.temp2.buf, "ABCDEFGHIJ", 10);
    one.temp2.x = 10;

    st_d two;
    two.temp3.a = 0;
    two.temp3.b = 0;
    two.temp3.c = 1;
    two.temp3.d = 0;
    two.temp3.e = 0;
    two.temp3.f = 0;
    two.temp3.g = 0;
    two.temp3.h = 0;
    memcpy(&two.buf1, "ABCDEFGHIJ", 10);
    two.x1 = 10;

    print_hex((unsigned char*) &one);
    print_hex((unsigned char*) &two);
    cout << sizeof(st_c) << " " << sizeof(st_a) << " " << sizeof(st_b) << " " << sizeof(st_d) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 5b 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a a 0 0 0
4 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 0 a 0 0 0
16 1 14 16
```

Note: I am using GCC version 4.4.x.

**Some notes about the output**:

In first line, `5b` is the padding byte introduced between `4` which is 1 byte `st_a` and `41` which is the first character of buffer of `st_b`.

In second line, `0` is the padding byte introduced between `4a` which is last character of buffer and `a` which is the integer following the character buffer in `st_d`.

Third line prints the size of all the structures.

Comment: When asking about compiler extensions, you should tell us what compiler you use.

Comment: @eerorika, I have updated my question!

Comment: @RaymondChen, I agree with you! Can you please clarify my other doubt, what if the size of the buffer inside `st_c` is of odd length?

Comment: No padding is needed in `st_d` after the `st_a` because the next field is an `unsigned char` which can be byte-aligned. Padding is needed in `st_c` after the `st_a` because the next field is an `st_b` which is marked as requiring 2-byte alignment. Imagine if there were a new structure `st_e` that was the same as `st_c` but with 4-byte alignment. You can't expect `st_d` to guess whether the `buf1` and `x1` are an inline `st_c` or an inline `st_e`.

Comment: I don't see any buffer in `st_c`. The buffers are in `st_b` and `st_d`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Ohh yeah, my bad, I meant `st_b`

Comment: Then `st_b` would be a (say) 9-byte `buf`, a padding byte, and then an `int`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I think you are absolutely right, can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not detecting the padding correctly. Are you expecting the padding to be zero bytes? There is no reason to expect that. The value in the padding bytes can be anything.
The zeroes you are seeing at the end are part of the 4 bytes of `st_b.x1`. It's value is 10 which as a little endian 2's complement integer with be stored as `0A 00 00 00`

```
04 5b 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 0a 00 00 00
^  ^  ^-----------------------------^---------^
|  |  st_b.buf                      st_b.x1  
|  random padding byte
|
st_a
```

A better way to look at the padding is to use the `offsetof` macro. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct Pack1 {
  char x;
};

#pragma pack(2)
struct Pack2 {
  short y;
};

struct Combined {
  struct Pack1 p1;
  struct Pack2 p2;
};
#pragma(pop)

int main()
{
  printf("offset of p1: %u, offset of p2: %u\n",
         offsetof(struct Combined, p1),
         offsetof(struct Combined, p2));
 return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
offset of p1: 0, offset of p2: 2
```

which clearly shows there is a single padding byte between `p1` and `p2`.

Another way to see the padding as zeroes would be to zeroize all the bytes of the struct right after it's declaration:

```
st_c one;
memcpy(&one, 0, sizeof(st_c);
```

Then the output of you program would look like:

```
04 00 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 0a 00 00 00
```

Comment: I know that `5b` is the padding byte. The issue is something different, please read the question carefully.

Comment: thanks for the effort though :-). I did learn something new: `offsetof`!

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. It would be clearer if you had reduced the problem to the bare essentials. There is a lot of extra code in your example that isn't relevant, like the bit fields in `st_a` and the int in `st_b`. I think Raymond Chen's comments answer your question.